# Is there anyway to get rid of the experience gained notification?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

In Batman Arkham Origins whenever you finish a battle the game will tell you how much xp (experience) you've gained, and it will give you a "threat level". After I saw this the first few times I knew it'd be annoying. Personally I don't need to be told how much I suck at fighting, I'm already aware of that.

So, is there anyway to disable this notification? I'm playing the PC version, so in-game solutions and external tools or mods are all acceptable.

Here are some screenshots of it:
[image: Image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: You don't mention what platform you're playing on?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I edited the tags.

Comment: I removed the tag and put it in the body of the question. (The tag is for problems directly *about* a PC, not for specifying that you want PC-based solutions. That's just accomplished by describing your platform in the body of the question.)

Comment: you can always put a sticker on your screen to cover these notifications :) And I guess you either have to get used to it, either write your own mod/hack/whatever to somehow hide it. I'm not aware of any existing mods for this game

Comment: There are a number of tasks that rely on this information, so I can't imagine why you'd want this.